# Magento image size increase after upload

Tags: magento-1.9, file-upload, varien-file-uploader, magento-1.9.3.6

We have a very strange issue using Magento 1.9.3.6

After uploading an image using the image uploader both for CMS Pages and Product we see that the image size increase 3-times.

The image we are uploading in our disk is 100kb after uploading through magento file uploader it becomes 300kb

Even with images already loaded all of them have been increased. It's weird.

We can't figure out the problem since in magento backend there is no setting for the image quality or image compression.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/196637/magento-1-9-increase-the-image-size-automatically

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/186405/supee-9767-patch-increasing-jpg-image-sizes/186418#186418

Comment: Updated to magento latest version and even with the patch doesn't work. Instead of copying link of thread that, obviously I already read before opening this, you should help to find a real solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SUPEE-9767 Patch increasing JPG image sizes](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/186405/supee-9767-patch-increasing-jpg-image-sizes)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Authorize.net - Authorize and Capture vs. Authorize Only](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1/authorize-net-authorize-and-capture-vs-authorize-only)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento 2: Cart Price Rules - Buy X get Y free (discount amount is Y) is Not Working](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/145529/magento-2-cart-price-rules-buy-x-get-y-free-discount-amount-is-y-is-not-wor)

Comment: @Jai duplicate of "Authorize.net - Authorize and Capture vs. Authorize Only"???

Comment: @ManojDeswal duplicate of "Magento 2: Cart Price Rules - Buy X get Y free (discount amount is Y) is Not Working"??? **Are you guys randomly selecting questions or something?**

Comment: revoke the close vote. My mistake and it seems close to (mentioned by @sv3n too ) https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/196637/29175 and https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/186405/29175

Answer (score 1):

It looks like an issue related to Magento, you have to modify the code or upload the images directly to the server without WYSIWYG editor.

Someone say it can be disabled with the new SUPEE-9767 patch.

"The image processing that was added in SUPEE-9767 patch is now optional. You may disable it by setting the config general/reprocess_images/active to 0 programmatically, but not via the Admin panel. Although, once you change it the image exploit will appear again."

Answer (score 0):

I have made this change in: `core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php`

from:

```
case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
  imagejpeg($img, $filePath, 100);
```

to

```
case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
  imagejpeg($img, $filePath);
```

and jpg loaded via wysiwyg editor retain their initial file size.

Comment: This is exactly the same as [your answer here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/223352)

Comment: Duplicate answers doesn't make the question a duplicate...